# understanding pointer logistics in printf statement

Tags: c, pointers, printf, dereference

I'm learning pointers in C but I'm slightly confused with this example. What is the pointer logistic for the  pointers in the three `printf()` statements below? What are these: `*(char*)ptr`, `*(int*)ptr`, `(char*)ptr+2`, exactly doing?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    void *ptr;
    char ch=74, *cp="CS107";
    int j=65;
    ptr=&ch;
    printf("%c\n", *(char*)ptr);
    ptr=&j;
    printf("%c\n", *(int*)ptr);
    ptr=cp;
    printf("%s\n", (char*)ptr+2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're already got your answer,  but just to clarify a *hidden* point, let me add some more info to already existing answers.

- `printf("%c\n", *(char*)ptr);`

  Cast the void pointer `ptr` to a `char` pointer, then de-reference to print the `char` value.
- `printf("%c\n", *(int*)ptr);`

  Cast the void pointer `ptr` to an `int` pointer, then de-reference to print the `char` representation of that `int` value.
- `printf("%s\n", (char*)ptr+2);`

  Here, the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) comes into play. As the cast operator will take precedence over binary addition, first the `ptr` will be casted to `char *`, and then, the pointer arithmetic will come into effect, incrementing the pointer to point to the 3rd `char` element (0 based indexing, remember?).

Answer (score 1):

`(char*)ptr` is called casting. A pointer of one type(`ptr`) is cast to point to a variable of another type(`char*`).

---

In your example, `ptr` is a pointer of type `void`, and it is used at various places to point to different types of variables.

`ptr=&ch;` this makes it point to a variable of type `char`.

However, the pointer `ptr` itself is of type `void` only, so later in `printf()` statement, it has to be explicitly casted to type `char*` to make it work.

```
printf("%c\n", *(char*)ptr);
                ^^^^^^^
```

Then, it is dereferenced to access the element residing in that memory.

```
printf("%c\n", *(char*)ptr);
               ^
```

---

Same goes for other types which follows.

Answer (score 1):

- `*(char*)ptr` : Treat the value of `ptr` as a pointer that pointing to `char` data, then read the `char` data pointed by `ptr`
- `*(int*)ptr` : Treat the value of `ptr` as a pointer that pointing to `int` data, then read the `int` data pointed by `ptr`
- `(char*)ptr+2` : Treat the value of `ptr` as a pointer that pointing to `char` data, then calculate a pointer pointing to a `char` data which is 2 elements ahead from the element pointed by `ptr`